# Entries problem with .pdf

Tags: cognito-forms

When I go in to the "Entries" and click on one of the listings below it opens up with all the data.

Payment summary and transaction summary. Then below that it shows all the completed form fields below. However when I click on the "Create Document" button it does create a .pdf. The .pdf when opened only lists the billing data. Data such as date, name, address are not shown.

So my real question is: it possible to create a .pdf of all the completed details on this form?

Comment: Hello! It is definitely possible to generate a PDF with all of your form data. Please submit a help request, and our support team can take a look at your particular form: https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/

Answer (score 0):

In Create Document, there a link underneath for Manage Templates. There you can edit each template and select what entry fields or blank fields you want generated in the PDF. You can also customize by downloading a Word template of the document to change it to the way you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the primary problem I had was the form being encrypted. As I have discovered recently no data will be transmitted :-)